# Recursive inorder Successor of a given element in BST with java

Tags: java, recursion, binary-search-tree, inorder

Because the code is too long the link is here ->http://pastebin.com/jXgbE6bB
Because i am not that good at recursions i just can't find the right recursion function for this problem.
(P.S.I am new to this forum and i know i am going to have a lot of hate comments like why not go find tutorials on recursions and other things,but believe me i have done everything but i just can't understand the logic of the recursions)
My question is What's the recursive function for in-order successor of a given element in Binary search tree?
I made it this far but it just returns the parent of the node it's supposed to print:

```
public E getSuccessor(BNode<E> t, E x) {
    if(t.left!=null && x.equals(t.info)){
        return t.left.info;
    }
    else if(x.compareTo(t.info)<0){
        return (getSuccessor(t.left, x));
    }
    else {
        return (getSuccessor(t.right, x));
    }
}

public E getSuccessor(E x) {
    return getSuccessor(root, x);
}
```

Comment: Can you specify your question and post the relevant code inside of your original question?

Comment: Sorry,i edited my post so now it should be more specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inorder successor of a given node is the lowest node in the right subtree of that node.  To understand otherwise, it is the next node that will be printed in a simple in order traversal of the tree.

1. If the node has a right child, this solution is simplified to finding the smallest node in the right subtree.
2. If the node doesn't have a right child, and there are no parent pointers, we need to start from the root of the tree and work our way to identify this successor.

Here is the recursive way to solve this.  While calling the method, pass root as the root of the tree, the node who's successor is needed as t and null as the successor because the method will calculate it.  Something like the following -

BinaryTreeNode successor=tree.inorderSuccessor(root,node,null);

```
public BinaryTreeNode<Type> inorderSuccessor(BinaryTreeNode<Type> root,BinaryTreeNode<Type> t,BinaryTreeNode<Type> successor)
{
    if(root==null)
        return null;
    if(root.element==t.element)
    {
        if(root.right!=null)
            return findMin(root.right);
        else
            return successor;
    }
    int cmp=t.element.compareTo(root.element);

    if(cmp < 0)
        return inorderSuccessor(root.left,t,root);
    else
        return inorderSuccessor(root.right,t,successor);
}

public BinaryTreeNode<Type> findMin(BinaryTreeNode<Type> t)
{
    if(t==null)
        return t;
    while(t.left!=null)
        t=t.left;
    return t;
}
```

Comment: But the point is i am not supposed to use a parent node only start from the root and find the successor of that element using recursions

Comment: Exactly what the program does - it uses only the root node.  It doesn't assume the use of a parent pointer.  Through the course of the program, we identify a node and call it the parent.  That is very different from using a parent pointer.  In fact let me rename everything to stop the confusion.

Comment: Tyvm for the explanation i got it now.